# Finding an object from an array by id in Underscore

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I have an array of objects as shown below:

```
var jsonarray = [{
    "id": "6",
    "equipment_img": "http://xxx:9696/XXX/images (1)_410.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "equipment_img": "http://xxx:9696/XXX/5.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "equipment_img": "http://xxx:9696/XXX/1_937.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "9",
    "equipment_img": "http://xxx:9696/XXX/4_335_631.jpg"
}];
```

I need to get `equipment_img` value  based on id 7.

```
var niches = _.pluck(jsonarray, 'id:7');

console.log(niches);
```

Could you please let me know if this is possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/vEDcx/17/

Comment: try _.find(jsonarray, function(o){ return o.id == 7; })

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dogLzmkx/ `niches = _.where(jsonarray, {id: "7"});`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need underscore to do this tersely. Use Array.prototye.filter (ES5):

```
var niches = jsonarray.filter(function(el) { el.id === 7 })[0].equipment_img
```

or Array.prototype.find (ES6):

```
var niches = jsonarray.find(function(el) { el.id === 7 }).equipment_img
```

(In either case you probably want to check whether the element exists before attempting to read `.equipment_img`)